# Training pretrained model keras_vggface produces very high loss after adding batch normalization

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to train my model using the pretrained [Keras VGGFace](https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface) on a dataset(all faces) of 1774 training images and 313 validation images consisting of 12 classes.

I have **recently added batch normalization and dropout in my code script** since it was overfitting. (My training acc was arround 99 and val acc. around 80). This is my code:

```
train_data_path = 'dataset_cfps/train'
validation_data_path = 'dataset_cfps/validation'

#Parametres
img_width, img_height = 224, 224

vggface = VGGFace(model='resnet50', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))

last_layer = vggface.get_layer('avg_pool').output
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
x1 = Dense(12, activation='sigmoid', name='classifier')(x)
x2 = BatchNormalization()(x1)
x3 = Dropout(0.5)(x2)
custom_vgg_model = Model(vggface.input, x3)

# Create the model
model = models.Sequential()

# Add the convolutional base model
model.add(custom_vgg_model)
```

When I try to train the model, the loss just goes above 10, which is not supposed to happen. Is the Batch Normalization and dropout layers added in the correct place?
I tried to adopt the code from their github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Batch normalization and dropout is being added after the sigmoid classification layer in your code. Dropout would cause some of the sigmoid activations or probabilities which are output by the Dense layer to not be considered, which is why there could be incorrect classification predictions while trying to find the class with maximum probability.

Please try modifying your code as follows, to include two Dense layers. The first hidden dense layer should have a dimension around half of the sum of the input and output dimensions. The final dense layer can be the layer for predicting the output class probabilities with sigmoid activation. The regularization layers can be added between the two layers.

```
train_data_path = 'dataset_cfps/train'
validation_data_path = 'dataset_cfps/validation'

    #Parametres
    img_width, img_height = 224, 224

    vggface = VGGFace(model='resnet50', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))

    last_layer = vggface.get_layer('avg_pool').output
    x = Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
    x1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
    x2 = BatchNormalization()(x1)
    x3 = Dropout(0.5)(x2)
    x4 = Dense(12, activation='sigmoid', name='classifier')(x3)
    custom_vgg_model = Model(vggface.input, x4)

    # Create the model
    model = models.Sequential()

    # Add the convolutional base model
    model.add(custom_vgg_model)
```